# Regex, how to match string into two groups without excluding the first line

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I tried using `(?P<Time>.+)\,\s(?P<Station>.+)`, but it did not capture the first line.

The sample strings aree:

```
9:21:13 AM
9:21:29 AM, TS729
9:21:33 AM, TS729
```

Tested at regex101.com:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?P<Time>[^,]+)(?:,\s*(?P<Station>.+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YWhjbZ/4) (switch to *Unit Tests*, the link is in the left pane).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<Time>[^,]+)` - `Time` group: any one or more chars other than a comma
- `(?:,\s*(?P<Station>.+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `,`  - a comma
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?P<Station>.+)` - one or more chars other than line break chars captured into Group "Station"
- `$` - end of string.

Unit tests screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your demo is empty =)

Comment: @JvdV Switch to Unit Tests.

Comment: Neat, never knew about unit tests. Shame you can't link directly to them

Comment: @Daniel What is your input? See [my regex used against a single multiline string](https://regex101.com/r/YWhjbZ/5).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew By using the query you provided, the first match for time I got 9:21:23 and 9:21:29. I need 9:21:23 to be the first match for time and 9:21:29 to be second match for time.

Comment: @Daniel Show you code snippet, I cannot repro. As you see in regex101, these are all separate matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  This second link you give worked out for me.

Comment: @Daniel if you use the strings as standalone inputs, both work for you.